# React-Native Realm on Android returns empty objects, works fine on iOS

Tags: android, react-native, realm

We have the following issue with our react-native (0.62.0) and realm (5.0.2)deployment:

We have a schema with a few models, one of which is `Location`. We can insert into location on both devices (ios and android) however, when we want to retrieve objects from it, it only works on ios.

```
 {
      name: 'Location',
      primaryKey: 'uuid',
      properties: {
        uuid: {type: 'string', indexed: true},
        id: {type: 'int'},
        title: 'string?',
        latitude: 'float?',
        longitude: 'float?',
        latitudedelta: 'float?',
        longitudedelta: 'float?',
        radius: 'float?',
      },
    },
```

We do the following to access our realm:

```
let repository = new Realm({schema:[{
      name: 'Location',..see above..}]});

export const LocationService = {
  findAll: function(sortBy) {
    let results = repository.objects('Location');
    console.log('LocationService.findAll', results);
    return results;
  },
};
```

When using iOS we have the following console.log:

```
LocationService.findAll {"0": {"id": 11, "latitude": 53.160179138183594, "latitudedelta": 0, "longitude": 10.146489143371582, "longitudedelta": 0.08983111381530762, "radius": 35, "title": "", "uuid": "16e1b034-f4b9-44d8-9f58-e30de82dd346"}, "1": {"id": 1, "latitude": 40.732025146484375, "latitudedelta": 0, "longitude": -74.00248718261719, "longitudedelta": 0.08983111381530762, "radius": 35, "title": "", "uuid": "ada51419-eea0-45ef-8209-581ce083a4fc"}, "2": {"id": 2, "latitude": 51.5080680847168, "latitudedelta": 0.2786773443222046, "longitude": -0.13921460509300232, "longitudedelta": 0.08983111381530762, "radius": 35, "title": "", "uuid": "4311470f-d790-4c40-a2b1-f210b723fa08"}, "3": {"id": 12, "latitude": 53.76025390625, "latitudedelta": 0, "longitude": 9.679306983947754, "longitudedelta": 0.08983111381530762, "radius": 35, "title": "", "uuid": "82b40618-051d-49b3-9281-334796e5660c"}}
```

Where as on Android we get the following console.log:

```
LocationService.findAll {"0": {}}
```

Later on in the code we have force access the id for instance:

```
let loadedLocations = LocationService.findAll();
    loadedLocations.forEach(l => {
      console.log(l.id);
    });
```

Again, on iOS we get the console.log outputs with the ID, whereas on android we only see undefined.

When attaching the debugger on the real device and inspecting it in the console, we can also see more on the results output:
[image]

Interestingly, on our other models in the schema we do not have this problem on Android. The android loads perfectly the other models. In the location case it does see, that there is one entry in the realm instance, and when we download the .realm file from the device (emulator && real testing device) we can see that the entries are correctly made!

What could be the problem, that only on this model, only on fetching the objects and only on android we run into this problem?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ? i am facing an exact same issue. Works as expected for ios. But for android i am getting undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update realm to the version 5.0.3
There is a bug on realm js 5.0.2 https://github.com/realm/realm-js/releases/tag/v5.0.3

Comment: i am using 5.0.3, But in both devices it prints empty object

Comment: I'm using 5.0.5 and the problem still exists.

Comment: It seems that this empty object issue can be "solved" by downgrading back to 3.6.5.